# Promise callbacks returning promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

With regard to these great two sources: [NZakas - Returning Promises in Promise Chains](https://github.com/nzakas/understandinges6/blob/master/manuscript/11-Promises.md#returning-promises-in-promise-chains) and [MDN Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), I would like to ask the following:

Each time that we return a value from a promise fulfillment handler, how is that value passed to the new promise returned from that same handler?

For instance,

```
let p1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve(42);
});

let p2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve(43);
});

let p3 = p1.then(function(value) {
    // first fulfillment handler
    console.log(value);     // 42
    return p2;
});

p3.then(function(value) {
    // second fulfillment handler
    console.log(value);     // 43
});
```

In this example, `p2` is a promise. `p3` is also a promise originating from `p1`'s fulfillment handler. However `p2 !== p3`. Instead `p2` somehow magically resolves to `43` (how?) and that value is then passed to `p3`'s fulfillment handler. Even the sentence here is confusing.

Could you please explain to me what exactly is going on here? I am totally confused over this concept.

Comment: `p2 somehow magically resolves to 43 (how?)` the "magic" is where you tell it to resolve to 43 ... `resolve(43);`

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the [magic of promises](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22562045/1048572) :-)

Comment: Do you understand how it works when you return a plain value, like `p3 = p2.then(function(value) { return value+1; })`?

Comment: @JaromandaX The magic is not in _what_ `p2` resolves to (43) but the fact that it was resolved at all, and not just passed through to the next function still as a promise.

Comment: how do you figure @Alec? both p1 and p2 are resolved promises - there is no magic about them being "resolved at all"

Comment: There's a difference between a resolved promise and its resolved value. OP was expecting `p3.then` to receive `p2`, a promise that's resolved to 43. Instead, it got the literal value 43, without any promise-wrapping at all.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Let’s say that throwing inside `then()` callback rejects the result promise with a failure, and returning from `then()` callback fulfills the result promise with a success value.

```
let p2 = p1.then(() => {
  throw new Error('lol')
})
// p2 was rejected with Error('lol')

let p3 = p1.then(() => {
  return 42
})
// p3 was fulfilled with 42
```

But sometimes, even inside the continuation, we don’t know whether we have succeeded or not. We need more time.

```
return checkCache().then(cachedValue => {
  if (cachedValue) {
    return cachedValue
  }

  // I want to do some async work here
})
```

However, if I do async work there, it would be too late to `return` or `throw`, wouldn’t it?

```
return checkCache().then(cachedValue => {
  if (cachedValue) {
    return cachedValue
  }

  fetchData().then(fetchedValue => {
    // Doesn’t make sense: it’s too late to return from outer function by now.
    // What do we do?

    // return fetchedValue
  })
})
```

This is why Promises wouldn’t be useful if you couldn’t **resolve to another Promise**.

It doesn’t mean that in your example `p2` would *become* `p3`. They are separate Promise objects. However, by returning `p2` from `then()` that produces `p3` you are saying **“I want `p3` to resolve to whatever `p2` resolves, whether it succeeds or fails”.**

As for *how* this happens, it’s implementation-specific. Internally you can think of `then()` as creating a new Promise. The implementation will be able to fulfill or reject it whenever it likes. Normally, it will automatically fulfill or reject it when you return:

```
// Warning: this is just an illustration
// and not a real implementation code.
// For example, it completely ignores
// the second then() argument for clarity,
// and completely ignores the Promises/A+
// requirement that continuations are
// run asynchronously.

then(callback) {
  // Save these so we can manipulate
  // the returned Promise when we are ready
  let resolve, reject

  // Imagine this._onFulfilled is an internal
  // queue of code to run after current Promise resolves.
  this._onFulfilled.push(() => {
    let result, error, succeeded
    try {
      // Call your callback!
      result = callback(this._result)
      succeeded = true
    } catch (err) {
      error = err
      succeeded = false
    }

    if (succeeded) {
      // If your callback returned a value,
      // fulfill the returned Promise to it
      resolve(result)
    } else {
      // If your callback threw an error,
      // reject the returned Promise with it
      reject(error)
    }
  })

  // then() returns a Promise
  return new Promise((_resolve, _reject) => {
    resolve = _resolve
    reject = _reject
  })
}
```

Again, this is very much pseudo-code but shows the idea behind how `then()` might be implemented in Promise implementations.

If we want to add support for resolving to a Promise, we just need to modify the code to have a special branch if the `callback` you pass to `then()` returned a Promise:

```
    if (succeeded) {
      // If your callback returned a value,
      // resolve the returned Promise to it...
      if (typeof result.then === 'function') {
        // ...unless it is a Promise itself,
        // in which case we just pass our internal
        // resolve and reject to then() of that Promise
        result.then(resolve, reject)
      } else {
        resolve(result)
      }
    } else {
      // If your callback threw an error,
      // reject the returned Promise with it
      reject(error)
    }
  })
```

Let me clarify again that this is not an actual Promise implementation and has big holes and incompatibilities. However it should give you an intuitive idea of how Promise libraries implement resolving to a Promise. After you are comfortable with the idea, I would recommend you to take a look at how actual Promise implementations [handle this](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/master/modules/es6.promise.js#L87-L90).

Comment: What a great explanation! Thank you for sharing your insight!

Comment: Very nice answer - I think it leaves a small gap by not implementing the caching behavior (which would be tiny) and there are a lot of other inaccuracies but it's definitely perfectly fine in the name of making the concepts approachable.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum If you can improve it without complicating it too much feel free to!

Comment: It is noteworthy that every function passed to `then` should have the type `a -> Promise b`, that is return another `Promise`. However, it was decided that `then` does the wrapping implicitly whenever a normal function `a -> b` is passed.

Answer (score 20):

Basically `p3` is  `return`-ing an another promise : `p2`. Which means the result of `p2` will be passed as a parameter to the next `then` callback, in this case it resolves to `43`.

Whenever you are using the keyword `return` you  are passing the result as a parameter to next `then`'s callback.

```
let p3 = p1.then(function(value) {
    // first fulfillment handler
    console.log(value);     // 42
    return p2;
});
```

Your code :

```
p3.then(function(value) {
    // second fulfillment handler
    console.log(value);     // 43
});
```

Is equal to:

```
p1.then(function(resultOfP1) {
    // resultOfP1 === 42
    return p2; // // Returning a promise ( that might resolve to 43 or fail )
})
.then(function(resultOfP2) {
    console.log(resultOfP2) // '43'
});
```

Btw, I've noticed that you are using ES6 syntax, you can have a lighter syntax by using fat arrow syntax :

```
p1.then(resultOfP1 => p2) // the `return` is implied since it's a one-liner
.then(resultOfP2 => console.log(resultOfP2));
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I would've been dealing with these issues forever!

Answer (score 6):

> > In this example, p2 is a promise. p3 is also a promise originating from p1's fulfillment handler. However p2 !== p3. Instead p2 somehow magically resolves to 43 (how?) and that value is then passed to p3's fulfillment handler. Even the sentence here is confusing.

a simplified version how this works (only pseudocode)

```
function resolve(value){
    if(isPromise(value)){
        value.then(resolve, reject);
    }else{
        //dispatch the value to the listener
    }
}
```

the whole thing is quite more complicated since you have to take care, wether the promise has already been resolved and a few more things.

Answer (score 6):

I'll try to answer the question *"why `then` callbacks can return `Promise`s themselves"* more canonical. To take a different angle, I compare `Promise`s with a less complex and confusing container type - `Array`s.

A `Promise` is a container for a future value.
An `Array` is a container for an arbitrary number of values.

We can't apply normal functions to container types:

```
const sqr = x => x * x;
const xs = [1,2,3];
const p = Promise.resolve(3);

sqr(xs); // fails
sqr(p); // fails
```

We need a mechanism to lift them into the context of a specific container:

```
xs.map(sqr); // [1,4,9]
p.then(sqr); // Promise {[[PromiseValue]]: 9}
```

But what happens when the provided function itself returns a container of the same type?

```
const sqra = x => [x * x];
const sqrp = x => Promise.resolve(x * x);
const xs = [1,2,3];
const p = Promise.resolve(3);

xs.map(sqra); // [[1],[4],[9]]
p.then(sqrp); // Promise {[[PromiseValue]]: 9}
```

`sqra` acts like expected. It just returns a nested container with the correct values. This is obviously not very useful though.

But how can the result of `sqrp` be interpreted? If we follow our own logic, it had to be something like `Promise {[[PromiseValue]]: Promise {[[PromiseValue]]: 9}}` - but it is not. So what magic is going on here?

To reconstruct the mechanism we merely need to adapt our `map` method a bit:

```
const flatten = f => x => f(x)[0];
const sqra = x => [x * x];
const sqrp = x => Promise.resolve(x * x);
const xs = [1,2,3];

xs.map(flatten(sqra))
```

`flatten` just takes a function and a value, applies the function to the value and unwraps the result, thus it reduces a nested array structure by one level.

Simply put, `then` in the context of `Promise`s is equivalent to `map` combined with `flatten` in the context of `Array`s. This behavior is extremely important. **We can apply not only normal functions to a `Promise` but also functions that itself return a `Promise`.**

In fact this is the domain of functional programming. A `Promise` is a specific implementation of a **monad**, `then` is `bind`/`chain` and a function that returns a `Promise` is a monadic function. When you understand the `Promise` API you basically understand all monads.

Comment: Thank you. The FP point of view is immensely clear in this case.