# Ionic 2 typescript variable always return undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic2

following is my code which I try to get data from API by passing the variables.

```
let currentPage;
let nextPage;
let leadsArray;
this.storage.get('current_page').then((val) => {
  currentPage = val;
  nextPage = currentPage + 1;
});

return new Promise(resolve => {
  this.http.get(this.webServiceUrl+'Inquiries/bwwFhAppTestApi3/'+this.clientId+'/'+nextPage)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(data => {
      //console.log(data);
      leadsArray = data.leads;
      this.storage.set('current_page', nextPage);
      resolve(leadsArray);
    });
});
```

when I inspect the HTTP request that variable `nextPage` is always rendered as undefined. These is nothing wrong with the `currentPage` variable as it is set to 1. Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: you said that `currentPage` and `val` are returning a number, correct? So if you `console.log(val + 1)` what do you get?

Comment: you need to chain your promises.. `this.storage.get` is asynchronous

Comment: @crash - Initially I set it to 1. So if I do `console.log(val + 1)` I get 2.

Comment: @suraj - Can you please help me by putting some sample code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35747957/promise-callbacks-returning-promises something like this

Answer (score 2):

You are calling two asynchronous functions

```
function1(){
let currentPage;
let nextPage;
let _this =this;
this.storage.get('current_page').then((val) => {
  currentPage = val;
  nextPage = currentPage + 1;
_this.function2(nextPage);
});
}

function2(nextPage){
let leadsArray;
return new Promise(resolve => {
  this.http.get(this.webServiceUrl+'Inquiries/bwwFhAppTestApi3/'+this.clientId+'/'+nextPage)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(data => {
      //console.log(data);
      leadsArray = data.leads;
      this.storage.set('current_page', nextPage);
      resolve(leadsArray);
    });
});
}
```

do something like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
doInfinite(infiniteScroll) {
  let currentPage;
  let nextPage;
  this.storage.get('current_page').then((val) => {
    currentPage = val;
    nextPage = currentPage + 1;

    this.webService.getOpenLeadsByPage(nextPage).then((result) => {
        for( var lead in result) {
            this.leads.push(result[lead]);
        }
        infiniteScroll.complete();
    });

  });
}
```

finally got it working by doing it this way inside my `home.ts`