# Returning from JavaScript Promise to Parent Function

Tags: javascript, node.js

The following logs "undefined" to the console while I'm intending it to log "return this":

```
function main() {
  promise()
    .then(function() { return "return this"});
}

console.log(main())
```

I think its returning the value "return this" to the main function, but then its not returning from the main function to be logged to the console. How could I change my code to make this work?

Comment: Your function doesn't actually return anything.  You need to return the promise.

Comment: Returning the promise returns "promise pending", its being returned before the promise is complete. How else could I do this?

Comment: Check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35747957/promise-callbacks-returning-promises

Comment: @tom894 You can't, that's the point of asynchrony.